# Sending a file from a server to a client connected via VPN

Tags: remote-access, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I connect my client laptop to a server via VPN and be able to send a file from the client to the server using the "**scp**" command.

Now, I want to send a file from the server back to the client using the "**scp**" command, but I got a permission denied message. I believe I have to setup a publickey of the sender on the receiver first before doing this, but whose publickey? Is it the VPN server's publickey or the server's publickey?

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer. I can simply run the "scp" command on the remote client to copy file from the server. I was trying to make thing complicate by trying to run scp command on the server, which is unnecessary and stupid.